# Meaning of $\max{f(x)}$ in a given range

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

> Let $f(x)=1+4x-x^2, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $g(x)= \max \{f(t):x \leq t \leq x+1 ; 0\leq x\leq 3\}$

I have quite basic doubt I know the meaning of $\min$ or $\max{g(x),h(x)}$ but what's the meaning of $\max{f(t)}$. It would be great if someone could explain by graph.

Comment: To type { in math mode you have to do \{ so "max\{f(t) ... \}"

Comment: $\text{max}(S)$ gives you the largest element (if it exists) of the set. In your case $S = \{f(t): x \leq t \leq x+1; 0 \leq x \leq 3 \}$ where $x$ is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are told that $g$ is a function defined on $[0,3]$.

For any $x$ in the domain of $g$ (that, is for a given $x\in[0,3]$), the value of $g(x)$ is computed by finding the largest value of $f$ on the interval $[x,x+1]$.

For example, $g(0)$ is the largest value of $1+4t-t^2$ as $t$ ranges between $0$ and $1$.

And $g(2)$ is the largest value of $1+4t-t^2$ as $t$ ranges between $2$ and $4$.

So that's why the rule for $g$ is
$$g(x) = \max_{x\leq t \leq x+1} (1+4t-t^2)$$

**Note:** If $x\leq 1$, then $g(x)= f(x+1)$ since the max of $f$ on $[x,x+1]$ is at the right endpoint.

Similarly, if $x \geq 2$, then $g(x) = f(x)$ since the max of $f$ on $[x,x+1]$ is at the left endpoint.

And if $x\in [1,2]$, then $g(x) = f(2)$ since the max of $f$ is the global max of $f$ and this is at $2$.

Comment: I understand this much, also isn't $g(1)$ largest $[0,1]$? I still don't understand how to make graph of the function.

Comment: The vertex of the graph of $f$ is at $x=2$, and the graph of $f$ is a parabola opening downwards, so on any interval completely contained in $(-\infty,2]$ the max is at the right endpoint, and on any interval completely contained in $[2,\infty)$ the max is at the left endpoint. For intervals containing $2$ in their interior, the max is at $2$. I will add a note in the answer.